# How to return a count column not exists in table by JPA

Tags: jpa

I want find a way to get extra column that count my records and return it in 1 mapping entity with extra filed.
I tried @transient on field but it will not return value when query.
Then I remove @transient but get an exception when save.
Also I tried @Formula but received null pointer exception.
Here's my repository code:

```
@Query(value = "select id,account,session_id,create_time,count from query_history a join " +
            "(select session_id sessionId,max(create_time) createTime,count(*) count from query_history group by session_id) b " +
            "on a.session_id = b.sessionId and a.create_time = b.createTime where account = ?1 order by create_time desc",
            countQuery = "select count(distinct(session_id)) from query_history where account = ?1",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<QueryHistory> findByNtAndGroupBySessionAndAction(String account, Pageable pageable);
```

entity code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "query_history")
@Data
public class QueryHistory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String account;

    @Column
    private Long sessionId;

    @Column
    private long createTime;

    @Transient
    private Integer count;
}
```

Sorry about my English and thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by projections [spring-data-projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), in fact I tried this before but in my sql:

```
select id,account,session_id,create_time,count
```

which should be:

```
select id,account,session_id sessionId,create_time createTime,count
```

PS:
projection interface:

```
public interface QueryHistoryWithCountProjection {
    Long getId();

    String getAccount();

    Long getSessionId();

    long getCreateTime();

    Integer getCount();
}
```